# Overpy or Overpass Turbo: How to get nodes by their IDs

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I got relation data using Overpy, and I got a list of member node IDs and member ways IDs.
As members of a relation, they don't have all their attributes.
So as another step I want to query Overpy by the list of IDs to get those nodes/ways with all their attributes.

Using the wizard in Overpass turbo I tried:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node["id"="1926700039"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

But it returns nothing.

How do I query nodes and ways by lists of IDs?

Comment: You know that you can fetch all relation members based on a relation id in a single query, right? Example: (rel(8015932);>;);out meta;

Comment: Nope.  I had no idea that was possible.  That's a great suggestion!  Can you recommend a source where I can learn the details of how to use these queries?  The documentation itself is too sparse with no examples.

Comment: Sorry, that question is way too broad for a comment, there are numerous sources out there. Did you try some web search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't get any answers or hints, nor could I find any examples of doing this (except in Overpass API, which has a slightly different syntax), but by trial and error I discovered the answer (which is actually very similar to the method for Overpass API).

For one node, this worked:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node(1926700039)({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

and for multiple nodes:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node(id:1926700039, 6224865808, 6186983783)({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
```

It works the same for ways as well.

Comment: You don't really need a bbox here, `node(id:1926700039, 6224865808, 6186983783); out body;` would be sufficient.